# Monitoring mouse coordinates while mouse button is pressed

Tags: javascript, mouse, mouseevent, mousemove

Is there a way in JS to keep track of changing `pageX` and `pageY` while you move mouse and hold mouse button?

Original HTML DOM Event object has it's `button` property, but if I try to monitor it on `mousemove`, it always returns me zero (unlike ctrlKey, shiftKey etc., for which it will reflect change).

I tried [jQuery Mousehold plugin](http://remysharp.com/2006/12/15/jquery-mousehold-event/), which waits for `mousedown`, sets interval, calls itself over and over and clears interval on mouseup or `mouseout`. It is good when you need to just catch mousehold, regardless of coordinates inside selector while button is held. But I need something to catch values during mousehold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set some flag variable on `mousedown`, and unset it in `mouseup`.
In `mousemove` handler simple check this variable.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a `mousemove` event on `body` instead of the element you originally clicked. In your `mousedown` handler, set some global variable specifying which element is active and a global boolean to indicate dragging. Also set your `mouseup` handler on `body`. Keep in mind however that this method will fail if these events are handled by other elements on the page and they stop bubbling.

Comment: Thanks, in my case there are no other handlers. It is for html5 canvas drawing, so methods are too resource-hungry to afford anything else on the page :)